# Have labels use different dataset than label dataset in chartjs line chart

Tags: chart.js

I have a dataset that has 1-2 entries per day and I don't want that many labels on the x-axis so I am going through them and only showing every 5th or 10nth one.  My issue is I do want to show the label for each one in the tooltips.  I have a second array or data with the original label set that I want to use for tooltips but can't seem to figure it out.  I assume there should be a fairly simple solution for this.

Below is a simple example.  I tried adding the cutom option on tooltips with the second dataset but no luck.

```
var labels = ["10-23-2017", "", "10-25-2017", ""];
var labels2 = ["10-23-2017", "10-24-2017", "10-25-2017", "10-26-2017"];


var chart = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
                    var myChart = new Chart(chart, {
                        // The type of chart we want to create
                        type: 'line',

                        // The data for our dataset
                        data: {
                            labels: labels,
                            datasets: [{
                                label: "Readings",
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                                data: data,
                            }]
                        },

                        // Configuration options go here
                        options: {
                            tooltip: [{
                                enabled: true,
                                custom: labels2
                            }]
                        }
                    });
```